# Connection refused error for Hadoop

Tags: hadoop

When I start my system and opens Hadoop. It gives error as "Connection refused".
When I format my name node using `hadoop nodname -format`, I'm able to access my Hadoop directory using `hadoop dfs -ls /`.
But every time I have to format my nodename.

Answer (score 0):

You can't just turn off your computer and expect Hadoop to pick up where it left off when turning the system back on

You need to actually run `stop-dfs` to prevent corruption in the Namenode and Datanode directories

Check both namenode and datanode logs to inspect why it's not starting if you do get "connection refused", otherwise it's a network problem